# How can I add hidden play audio for Rails app using Bootstrap and Heroku

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, html5-audio

Halo ! app experts!
I like to add my idea to my web-site which is deployed in Heroku using Bootstrap and Rails 4.
I have about 5~6 different pages in `app/views` folder

## My idea is this:

1. When user comes to the 'landing page' which is `views/home/index.html.erb`, the user can click on a picture then can start hear the background music for whole web. I mean once the user clicked the picture(in index.html.erb), the user should able to hear the background music whereever the user goes into different pages.
2. If the user left the web or closed the ex)chrome or safari, and comes back to the my web-app, the background music should't there. The user must go back to the `views/home/index.html.erb` page and click the picture to start listen the background music agian.

Is it... possible? If so, Can you please guide me or teach me?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio playback can not be continues when a user navigates away from one page to another. To make it constantly play, the page that the audio is playing (`home/index.html.erb`) must not be navigated away.

This means that you have to load your page content using AJAX. Since, jQuery is already loaded with your Rails app, use its `$('#your-main-content').load('/another-page')` method to load content to your page.